# Why won't it print anything?

Tags: java

This is the code I have written. But the code does not print anything even though it is compiling. I have also tried to include  System.out.print statements under the if and else statements. What am I supposed to do in order to have it actually print something.

```
public class Numfive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        isReverse("hello", "eLLoH");
    }

    public static boolean isReverse(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1.length() == 0 && s2.length() == 0) { 
            return true;
        } else if (s1.length() == 0 || s2.length() == 0) {
            return false;  // not same length
        } else {
            String s1first = s1.substring(0, 1);
            String s2last = s2.substring(s2.length() - 1);
            return s1first.equalsIgnoreCase(s2last) &&
            isReverse(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(0, s2.length() - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you *don't have* any print statement (that prints the result).

```
System.out.println(isReverse("hello", "eLLoH"));
```

**Note:**

> I have also tried to include System.out.print statements under the if and else statements.

If you put a print statement after the `if-else if-else` structure, the program won't never reach it, because each block has a `return`.

Comment: I just love it when I make mistakes like this haha :)